# What does Xcode expect for the "Binding<Bool>" placeholder?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I have a struct as shown below. There's a binding var that is a Bool. For the preview, what does Xcode expect in place of the `Binding<Bool>` placeholder? `true` and `false` return the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'".

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailShellView : View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var testMessage: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isPresented = false
                print("variable message: \(self.testMessage)")
            }) {
                Text("Close modal view")
            }
            Text(testMessage)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailShellView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailShellView(isPresented: <#Binding<Bool>#>, testMessage: "donuts")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because SwiftUI expects that you pass a value to `DetailShellView`, but you are not passing anything. For example:

I expect oranges, and you give me <<#Fruit#>>. It's a silly example, but the point is that on your class, you need to pass an actuall bool value, so Biding is a way of saying, I'm getting the value from somewhere else and I'll use it. Your class `DetailShellView` is expecting such value.

So what you can do is pass in an actual value like so:

```
struct DetailShellView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailShellView(isPresented: .constant(true), testMessage: "donuts")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can preview both states, eg. as follow

```
static var previews: some View {
  Group {
    DetailShellView(isPresented: .constant(true), testMessage: "donuts")
    DetailShellView(isPresented: .constant(false), testMessage: "donuts")
  }
}
```